# Transformation between a hypercube and a polygon?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, transformation, transformational-geometry

Is there a straightforward way to generalize the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315828/transformation-between-square-and-a-polygon) to how to transform the points within a square to a polygon to n-dimensional cubes and polygons? Specifically, given a convex region $\mathcal{C}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, bounded by hyperplanes on all sides, is there a one-to-one mapping between this region and the hypercube $[0,1]^n$?

A region I'm thinking of would be something like
$$
\mathcal{C}:\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\big|\; 0\leq x\leq2,
-1\leq y \leq 3, -3\leq z \leq -1, \\
-1\leq 2x-y+z, 0\leq x+y\leq 3 \}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [convex body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_body), $C$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $[0, 1]^n$. To see this, pick a point $p$ in the interior of $C$ and choose $\alpha > 0$ small enough such that $D = p + \alpha[0, 1]^n$ is contained in the interior of $C$. Then design a radial projection $f : C \to D$ that maps a point $c$ on the boundary of $C$ to the point $c_0$ where the line segment $[p, c]$ meets the boundary of $D$ and maps $p + \lambda (c - p)$ to $p + \lambda (c_0 - p)$ for $0 \le \lambda < 1$. Composing $f$ with the obvious affine homeomorphism from $D$ to $[0, 1]^n$ gives the homeomorphism you are asking for.

Comment: To clarify: if I want to map a point $q$ to $D$, I need to compute the point $c$ that lies on the boundary of $\mathcal{C}$ and is collinear with $p$ and $q$, correct? Then, given this $c$, I can take $\lambda=\frac{q-p}{c-p}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.